# Advice on writing xslt file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

i have xml file such as following.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='AdditionalLogInfo.xsl'?>
<Logs>
  <Log TestName="EwireDepositTests" Date="Oct 3 11">
    <Item>
      <Message>Name: blabla</Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Message>Test Status: Failed</Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Message>
      </Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Message>[[Logs]]</Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Message>[ccpayment]</Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Exception>blabla couldn't be found in the database</Exception>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Message>
      </Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Message>[logging]</Message>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Exception>couldn't be found in the database</Exception>
    </Item>
  </Log>
</Logs>
```

The problem i'm got stuck into is writing an xslt file so that I could view good-looking html page with red lines if there is Exception node in Logs/Log/Item and green lines if there is Message node instead.

Comment: what xslt do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//Item/*[normalize-space(.)]"/>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Message">
    <li style="color:green" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Exception">
    <li style="color:red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

[image]